# Take full screen's screenshot iOS

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of full length tableview starting from 0th row to 30th row. (including navigation bar)

Following is the code I implemented which takes screenshot of only visible screen:

```
func takeScreenShot() -> UIImage {

    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot!, nil, nil, nil)

    return screenshot!
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This one saved me:

https://github.com/davidman/DHSmartScreenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);`

To work with the length of the tableview

Something like this:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tableView.contentSize.height, false, scale);`

I haven't tested the above but you get the general idea.

Edit: **This will need to be modified slightly to include the nav bar, you would have to add the heights of the tableview and navbar together.**

Comment: height is of type CGFloat and size if of type CGSize. Expected input parameter must be of CGSize type